# What societal or economic pressures would cause a martian settlement to fight earth?

Tags: science-based, society, space-colonization, military

In this world our hero is martian and fighting against earth alongside the rest of mars, its set in the early 2100s but there's one problem. Why would mars want to fight earth? Things to know:

- earth and mars have global governments
- mars only has around 10 million inhabitants
- lots of money goes into space programs
- all of mars is fighting all of earth
- mars is at the leading edge of technology

I have been trying to think of a way to explain the war but most things I come up with don't make much sense like "mars needs more supply missions" because they have farms and factories. So I ask: what societal, economic or other pressures would cause a martian settlement to fight earth?

Comment: If Mars has 10 million inhabitants (the population of Michigan or Greece), then it doesn't need *supply missions* of *space programs*. It must have functioning industries and infrastructure and economy, especially to support that "leading edge of technology". It has *trade*.

Comment: thats exactly why i said it didnt make sense.  it was an example of my bad thinking, which is why i came here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Religion

The other guys are praying to the wrong God. Enough said.

## Nazism

Either side is committing genocide. You don't debate genocide, you stop it with whatever means you have.

## Independence

Earth is trying to take over Mars in order to levy a tax on tea. Mars will have to fight if they don't want to pay.

## Freedom

Large oil reserves have been found under Martial soil. Mars now needs some freedom.

You may think that Mars could just sell that oil. But no oil is as cheap as free oil.

## Smoke screen for some political problem

You are a president. You are facing recession, corruption scandals and whatnot. A war would distract voters from such problems.

Comment: Oil in Martian soil and USA (USE now, United States of Earth) want take democracy to the green people! But wait... 2100 they will still use it?

Comment: @rodolfo-penteado the martians are actually humans but descendants of the first settlers to go to mars. and i was thinking a UN type organisation would take over but the USE sounds good so im stealing that name (:

Comment: Software developers on both planets secretly arranged the war to be able to drop half of timezones database.

Comment: @user28434 Totes approve.